# Simple XML read element namespace attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML, schema below

```
$xml = 
'<NodeSet
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd">
    <Node category="category" i:type="ObjectNode">
        <NodeId>
            <Identifier>i=86</Identifier>
        </NodeId>
    </Node>
</NodeSet>';
```

I need to extract the **i:type** attribute value from the Node element. I have tried accessing it as i would do it when accessing normal attributes but it seems it doesn't work that way

Here is how i can access the category attribute,

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->Node[0]['category']; //this prints 'category' as expected
echo $xml->Node[0]['i:type']; //prints nothing, how do i get the i:type attribute value ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the attributes with the namespace, this can be done using the `attributes()` method...

```
echo $xml->Node[0]->attributes("i",true)['type'];
```

Using `("i",true)` says use the i prefix rather than having to put the URI.

Comment: Thanks @nigel-ren , Problem solved.

Comment: Just a note that relying on the prefix may or may not be a good idea depending how the XML is generated. Some XML processors will arbitrarily assign different prefixes to the same URI, so your code may break if you relied on that.